# Automatically adding methods for (@property) UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I declared an UIButton in header file.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *fooButton;
```

And in implementation file, I can find reserved method as follows. ( I mean xcode help input completion.)

```
- (void)removeFooButton:(NSSet *)objects
```

I also find "removeFooButtonAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes" and so on.
What's purpose for implementing these methods?
Thanks.

Comment: Aren't clear from the method name?

Comment: Exactly, I can find "- (void)setFooButton:(UIButton *)fooButton", too.

Comment: there would be around 10s of these... :)

Comment: Method setfoobutton is the default setter and method foobutton is the default getter for the foobutton that you have created.